# JBoss won't use the Oracle DataSource driver from the correct module when 2 different versions are in 2 separate modules

Tags: java, oracle, configuration, jboss, datasource

I am running an application under JBoss 7 (Java 1.7) which connects to an Oracle 10.2.0.3 database using `ojdbc14.jar`.

The same application also has to connect to an different Oracle database, 12.1.0.2 for which I have an `ojdbc7.jar`.

Each Oracle driver jar was placed in its own JBoss module:

```
D:\Jboss\jboss-7.2.0.Final\modules\com\Oracle\ojdbc7\main\ojdbc7.jar
D:\Jboss\jboss-7.2.0.Final\modules\com\Oracle\ojdbc14\main\ojdbc14.jar
```

Assume the `module.xml` files are correct (they are; the `ojdbc#.jar.index` file gets created).

In `standalone.xml`, I declared the following under `<drivers>`:

```
                <driver name="oracle14" module="com.oracle.ojdbc14">
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver> 
                <driver name="oracle7" module="com.oracle.ojdbc7">
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
```

For my datasources, I did the following:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/OracleTen" pool-name="OracleTen-DEV" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ORACLE10DEV:49125:databasename</connection-url>
    <driver>oracle14</driver>
    ... 
</datasource>
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/OracleTwelve" pool-name="OracleTwelve-DEV" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ORACLE12DEV:1521:databasename</connection-url>
    <driver>oracle7</driver>
    ...
</datasource>
```

When trying to run against the Oracle 12 datasource, it uses the Oracle 10 driver, as evidenced by the code throwing:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:283)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:278)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.receiveOsesskey(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:294)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:357)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:439)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:254)
... 18 more
```

When I comment-out the `oracle14` driver and the datasource using it in `standalone.xml`, the Oracle 12 datasource runs as expected.

I assume this is some sort of classloader issue, but weren't modules supposed to solve this problem?  What should I do to allow both to connect without issues?

I have not yet attempted to make the Oracle 10 datasource reliant on the Oracle 12 drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ojdbc14.jar`. Use `ojdbc7.jar` in both/all modules.

The 12.1.0.2 driver is backwards compatible with a 10.2.0.3 server.

The matrix on [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02) doesn't cover 10.2, but it says:

> Best Practice that we recommend is, JDBC driver version should always be either same as **or higher than** the Oracle database version being used in order to leverage the latest capabilities of the JDBC driver.